# Same Origin Policy LAN

Tags: javascript, html, web-services, same-origin-policy

i have a problem with the SOP.
I want to develop a Web-Based-Application witch HTML, JS etc. this App have to run on localhost. I don't want to have a webserver.
I have a device in the LAN, which I can't edit or something. On this device is a https rest service. Therefrom i want to get data.

If I want access to the rest service the browser throws an error, which says I cant access to this site because of the SOP.

```
var xmlHttp = createRequest();
xmlHttp.open("GET", url, false);
xmlHttp.send();
return xmlHttp.responseText;
```

Thats my code. I hope you can help me.

Comment: "I don't want to have a webserver" — What do you think is providing `http://192.168.192.1:8443`? You already have a web server.

Comment: Yes but it's not ym web server. The Client Webapp schould run local

Answer (score 0):

In short, it seems you can't place requests on servers other than the one from which the page was served *unless* the server explicitly permits it. [This page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) explains how clients should place such requests, and [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Server-Side_Access_Control) covers how servers should respond.

Comment: I get this error: http://fs5.directupload.net/images/160307/qs3pvkpu.png it's german but i think you can see what i mean

Comment: @D.Schöneborn — It says, if I'm translating it correctly, that the response doesn't have an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header on it … so add an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to the response. Google will help you find the correct syntax.

Comment: Ok I'm going to have to change my answer ! In short, it seems you can't place requests on servers other than the one from which the page was served *unless* the server explicitly permits it. The mozilla pages that explain this are [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Server-Side_Access_Control)